# How to fly enemies like galaxian game enemies?

Tags: box2d, cocos2d

I am developing game like galaxian and using cocos2d with box2d .I don't have idea how to create enemies like galaxian game enemies and how do they fly over the screen.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmrCd5tPqpo&feature=related

Could you please help me how to do this ?

I have created the enemies but when i look at the game enemies fly how they are flying ?

Comment: What movement are you trying to recreate? What have you tried?

Comment: I have created the enemies but when i look at the game enemies fly how they are flying ?

Comment: @jubin their X and Y coordinates change.

Comment: To make them fly curves take a loot at Bézier curves: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: @jubin "How do I make them fly?" is really vague and broad - you just change their positions, after all! If you're asking for a specific way to make them fly, like the ones that fly in a curve, you should specify that.

Answer (score 3):

Initialise and assign a movement function to each enemy as a function of time for e.g.

```
x(t) = 5 * sin(t)
y(t) = t * 0.2

final position = Point(x(t), y(t))
```

when they start flying, plug in the game elasped time since start of flight into x(t) and y(t) to give you the new X and Y coordinate of the enemy.

A boss movement function could be e.g.

```
x(t) = 10 * sin(0.2 * t)
y(t) = cos(0.2 * t)
```

NOTE: depending on the coordinate system of your game, you may need negative functions.